# Show Back Arrow in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to show Back Arrow in Fragments ToolBar. Im trying to write this code:  `((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`

but AS writes: **method invokation .. may produce "java.lang.NullPointerException".** What about **getSupportActionBar()**, AS writes cannot resolve method. Whats wrong? Here is my code:

```
public class AddFilterFrag extends android.app.Fragment  {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);       
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_filter_layout, container, false);
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        return rootView;
    }
 @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

       inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_menu, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            //something to do
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: You need to set home button as enabled in the activity that contains the fragment.

Comment: It looks like you have a platform Fragment being used within an app compat Activity.  Typically you don't mix the two.  App compat library fragments are used in app compat library activities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Frist add method to your activity that call fragment.

   public void changeToolbar(){
   //Do your job
   }
2. call it in fragment

   ((YourActivity)getActivity).changeToolbar();

Answer (score 6):

This is just a warning you can safely ignore.

**Background:**

The Android sdk has Annotations to help developers avoid common mistakes. One of those annotations is `@Nullable`. The method `getSupportActionBar()` is annotated as such, as it is possible that `null` is returned from that method. One case might be, that the developer used the theme `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` thus disabling the ActionBar.

If you have an ActionBar or a Toolbar in your layout (and set it properly) that method will never return `null`. You can ignore the warning like this:

```
//noinspection ConstantConditions  
((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Or if you want to be absolutely safe:

```
ActionBar ab = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();  

if(ab != null){  
    ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);  
}
```

**Alternatively in Kotlin:**

`(activity as? AppCompatActivity)?.supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)`

Comment: that's correct. You can either ignore it or put a null check before it. Adding the statement in an activity (as other answers suggest) would make not difference.

Answer (score 1):

while using navigation graphs use navController to do that

On the activity thats holding the host fragment do this

```
lateinit var navController : NavController
```

In oncreateView

```
navController = this.findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController)
```

override onSupportNavigateUp

```
override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return navController.navigateUp()
    }
```

that handles the up arrow by itself.

Answer (score 0):

After setContentView() method, you put given below code.

First you must set the toolbar then you try use getSupportActionBar().

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
     getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);}
```

I hope this help you.